# Connect two D1 R2 (8266) via SPI with Github SPISlave Library

Tags: esp8266, spi

**Problem:**
SPI Connection between two D1 (ESP8266) boards does not work properly, only master to slave transfers data correctly.

**What I did:**
I connected two Wemos D1 R2 via SPI and installed the library from https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino. I connected MISO, MOSI, SCK, SS and ground 1:1. On one D1 I run SPISlaveTest on the other SPIMaster from the examples. The D1 are located directly beside each other, cables are only 15 cm long.

**Effect:**
While the slave receives strings from the master fine the master seems to get crippeled answers from the slave, they appear as ??? and other characters. If I connect the slaves SS to +3.3V it reacts like expected: The slave receives no more, the master gets no reponses.

**What I already tried:**

- Updated the Libraries to the latest versions
- Changed delay to wait for answer
- tried SafeMaster.ino
- Changed D1 hardware on both sides

Everything unfortunately did not help.

Any tip is very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try swapping the master and slave devices

Comment: install esp8266 arduino core in IDE board manager and the spislave library is part of that package. you do not need GitHub for that

Comment: did you connect ground between D1 R2s?

Comment: I connected ground and also opened this connection as they are both connected to the same computer via usb no difference. And yes, I installed the library through the board manager. Also I swapped devices because I have several D1.

Comment: If the corruption is unidirectional is there an issue with your MISO line?

Comment: I swapped and exchanged hardware, also the wires.